# OSX Server _www access to samba mounted directory

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, samba, mac-osx-server

I am having issues automatically mounting a smb share on our osx 10.6 server so that _www has the permissions to read the presented files.

If I mount using the graphical auto-mount utility supplied in osx, the operating system does not allow access to the files as _www

I have been able to get around this by issuing:

`sudo -u _www mount_smbfs //sambauser:password@<ip addr>/ShareName /tmp/my_mnt`

But this obveously requires a superuser password to be entered, I could easily do this on a Linux box in fstab by putting `//host/share /path/to/mount/point smbfs username=remotename,password=remotepass,uid=_www 0 0` in `fstab` but seeing as osx has all-but done away with fstab I am unable to do so.

Is there something obveous I'm missing here?

Thanks

Stewart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is stolen directly from http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100203124656707

1. Add a new line to /etc/auto_master

   ```
    /-     auto_smb
   ```
2. Put this in /etc/auto_smb

   ```
    /path/to/mountpoint -fstype=smbfs ://user:password@server/share
   ```
3. Create the mountpoint

   ```
    mkdir /path/to/mountpoint
    chmod 755 /path/to/mountpoint
   ```
4. Restart